# Positioning in drag and drop layout

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt

i have a few problem here regarding the drag and drop. I already create the code for drag and drop, its working finely. But here's the problem, as u can see in the images below each jar can fits only 4 sweets, but when i drag sweets from the second jar to the first one, it can still be drop into it. How can i make each jar can only be fixed with four sweets?

This is the coding that I've done for the drag and drop. Should I use the if else statement somewhere in this coding to solve my problem?

```
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
    // Do nothing
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup

    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    owner.removeView(view);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
    container.addView(view);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
    //v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    if (dropEventNotHandled(event))
    {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
  return true;
}

private boolean dropEventNotHandled(DragEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return !event.getResult();
}
  }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

inside the `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` block you should be checking to see if theres room in the jar and if not then return `false` so that the drop action fails.

Comment: how to check if there is room in the jar?

Comment: there is no way of us to tell you that since we can't see the rest of your code... you need to look for where in the program the sweets are assigned to jars

Comment: the sweets are already in the jar. would you like to see the xml code?

Comment: I think in your case it may be better for you to do a bit more reading so you can understand your source code.